# How to Remove Addtoany.min.js on Homepage?

Tags: wordpress

I want to remove Addtomany.min.js (created by AddToAny Share Buttons WordPress Plugin) on Homepage/Archive.

I don't setup to display share button on homepage, so this file is unnecessary.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Mark](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/254417/76745) answer.

You just need to replace `jquery` with AddToAny handle.

Comment: The Handle you want to remove is 'addtoany'